# Is there something wrong with the code or it is a bug of NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

recently I installed netbeans 12.0, I noticed that when running a project, it always executes the scanner before the output of print.
Such as.

System.out.print("Name : ");

String name = scanner.nextLine();

and returning an output like this if I entered John while executing:

John

Name:

desired output

Name: John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in your print statement:

```
    System.out.println("Name: ");
```

What should have happened was this:

```
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
```

So what I did was I'm assigning the "name" variable first, and then I'm concatenating 2 strings together ("concatenating" basically means putting 2 strings together).